# What is a proper way for naming of message properties in i18n?

Tags: internationalization, naming-conventions

We do have a website which should be translate into different languages. Some of the wording is in message properties files ready for translation. I want now add the rest of the text into these files.

What is a good way to name the text blocks?

```
<view>.<type>.<name>
```

We mostly have webpages and some of the elements/modules are repeating on some sites.

Comment: Is this java properties or .NET?

Comment: Great question! What you have described above is a great guideline for naming of properties.  Unfortunately this is also a very subjective area.  I'd like to see what the rest of the community suggests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know, no "standard" exists. Therefore it is pretty hard to tell what is proper and what is improper way of naming resource keys. However, based on my experience, I could recommend this way:

```
property file name: <module>.properties
resource keys: <view or dialog>[.<sub-context>].<control-type>.<name>
```

We may discuss if it is proper way to put every strings from one module into one property files - probably it could be right if updates doesn't happen often and there are not so many messages. Otherwise you might think about one file per view.

As for key naming strategy: it is important for the Translator (sounds like film with honorable governor Arnold S. isn't it?) to have a Context. Translation may actually depend on it, i.e. in Polish you would translate a message in a different way if it is page/dialog/whatever title and in totally different way if it is text on a button.

One example of such resource key could be:

```
preferences.password_area.label.username=User name
```

It gives enough hints to the Translator about what it actually is, which could result in correct translation...

Comment: Keep in mind DRY principles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). If a property is used in multiple places and isn't likely to change, consider a property name like 'common.button.submit=Save'. By extension consider removing the UI duplication with taglibs or templates.

Comment: even tho it is very tempting to reuse translations such as close, save, ok... it is not a good idea because save sometimes means "Save document" in other place "Save product". Also in other languages it could be apropriate to use 2 different terms instead of the generic save/close/ok etc...

Comment: @Vitim.us How would "Save" be different for save document vs save product? It seems the important fact is what the UI context is (button, header, input label, tooltip, etc), for example [MDN says to not re-use keys in different contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_content_best_practices#Dont_reuse_strings_in_different_contexts), but does not seem to expand that to mean different views. If I understand correctly, a "Save" button is a "Save" button and can be re-used, but should just not be re-used for a "Save" header or "Save" input label, etc.

Comment: @AaronBeall Maybe in english, the world save would be appropriated in most cases, but in other languages, it could have different verbs depending on what the subject is. In portuguese for example a button called `Select All` would have different strings depending on what you're selecting. So you can't reuse `Select All` inside a Brand and a Product dropdown for example. It would be `Selecionar todos` inside Produtos (products), and `Selecionar todas` inside Marcas (brands)

Comment: @Vitim.us That makes sense, thanks. I guess it's hard to wrap my head around because buttons in English don't necessarily refer to anything, at least by name, but we have to think about what the subject actually is. So then is it safe to say that something like `save.document.button` would be common and re-usable? What I'm trying to avoid are verbose namespaces that don't provide any value and result in duplication.

Answer (score 11):

We have come up with the following key naming convention (Java, btw) using dot notation and camel case:

**Label Keys** (form labels, page/form/app titles, etc...i.e., not full sentences; used in multiple UI locations):

If the label represents a Java field (i.e., a form field) and matches the form label: **label.nameOfField**
Else: **label.sameAsValue**

Examples:

- label.firstName = First Name
- label.lastName = Last Name
- label.applicationTitle = Application Title
- label.editADocument = Edit a Document

**Content Keys:**

**projectName.uiPath.messageOrContentType.n.***

Where:

- **projectName** is the short name of the project (or a derived name from the Java package)
- **uiPath** is the UI navigation path to the content key
- **messageOrContentType** (e.g., added, deleted, updated, info, warning, error, title, content, etc.) should be added based on the type of content. Example messages: (1) The page has been updated. (2) There was an error processing your request.
- **n.*** handles the following cases: When there are multiple content areas on a single page (e.g., when the content is separated by, an image, etc), when content is in multiple paragraphs or when content is in an (un)ordered list - a numeric identifier should be appended. Example: **...content.1**, **...content.2**
  When there are multiple content areas on a page and one or more need to be further broken up (based on the HTML example above), a secondary numeric identifier may be appended to the key. Example: **...content.1.1**, **...content.1.2**

Examples:

- training.mySetup.myInfo.content.1 = This is the first sentence of content 1. This is the second sentence of content 1. This content will be surrounded by paragraph tags.
- training.mySetup.myInfo.content.2 = This is the first sentence of content 2. This is the second sentence of content 2. This content will also be surrounded by paragraph tags.
- training.mySetup.myInfo.title = My Information
- training.mySetup.myInfo.updated = Your personal information has been updated.

**Advantages / Disadvantages**:

---

+ Label keys can easily be reused; location is irrelevant.
+ For content keys that are not reused, locating the page on the UI will be simple and logical.

- It may not be clear to translators where label keys reside on the UI. This may be a non-issue for translators who do not navigate the pages, but may still be an issue for developers.
- If content keys must be used in more than one location on the UI (which is highly likely), the key name choice will not make sense in the other location(s). In our case, management is not concerned with a duplication of values for content areas, so we will be using different keys (to demonstrate the location on the UI) in this case.

---

Feedback on this convention - especially feedback that will improve it - would be much appreciated since we are currently revamping our resource bundles! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd propose the below convention

```
functionalcontext.subcontext.key
logicalcontext.subcontext.key
```

This way you can logically group all the common messages in a super context (id in the below example). There are few things that aren't specific to any functional context (like lastName etc) which you can group into logical-context.

```
order.id=Order Id
order.submission.submit=Submit Order
name.last=Last Name
```

Answer (score 2):

the method that I have personally used and that I've liked more so far is using sentence to localisee as the key. For example: (pls replace T with the right syntax dependably on the language)

for example:
  print(T("Hello world"))

in this case T will search for a key "Hello world". If it is not found then the key is returned, otherwise the value of the key.

In this way, you do not need to edit the message (in your default language) at least that you need to use parameters.... It saved me a LOT of dev time

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that you don't have a full file to give to the translator worth the correct key and translation in your default language. Another disadvantages is that you don't test if your key works with the translation file.